# Does the size of a Windows Form include its Border?

Tags: c#, winforms, size, border

When you set the size of a windows form, ie;

```
Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 500);
```

Does this include the border which windows puts around the form? Because I have added images (via pictureBoxes) which are 700x500 to my form, and they have been cut off by the border.

Also: When I say the border, I mean the default windows border which you can drag the edges of to resize it, as well as contain the red X, Minimize, and Maximize buttons.

Comment: fairly sure thats a yes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends, you'll get a different size when you target .NET 4.5 for example.  The border is always included but you don't really know how much of the border is included.  An issue with the fat borders you get with Aero and the skinny ones you get in XP.

It is almost always the wrong thing to do.  You always want to assign the *ClientSize* property instead.  Important, it doesn't include the borders so you can be sure that controls still fit.

And *hard-coding* the size is always wrong as well.  Your form will be *rescaled*, depending on the video adapter's dots-per-inch setting.  The larger the DPI setting, the bigger the form needs to be to still fit its content.  So the correct statement ought to resemble this:

```
  this.ClientSize = new Size(PictureBox3.Right, PictureBox3.Bottom);
```

On the assumption that "PictureBox3" is the control in the far right-bottom corner that you want to keep visible.  This statement needs to appear in the Load event handler to ensure that rescaling was done, it can't work in the constructor.  One of the very few good reasons to use the Load event.

Comment: There is something I don't understand here, what if I know the PictureBox3's Size beforehand. Do you mean that size can be changed depending on DPI? I mean the pair of numbers (x,y) that corresponds to that size (not the actual absolute size for example calculated in centimeters, inches, ...). I think the PictureBox3's Size is already in Points, and the actual absolute size depends on that Size (in Points) and DPI. I guess the your code line above will be translated into something like: `this.ClientSize = new Size(700,500);` first before any other process. Any explanation?

Comment: It is pixels, not points or inches.  The Font size is specified in points.  Not a match made in heaven, that's why the form's AutoScaleMode property defaults to Font.  And that's why you don't know the size beforehand.

Comment: For clarification, my form has its properties modified so that it cannot be maximized or resized by the user.

Comment: Just set the FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle so you don't need this kind of code *and* it is obvious to the user as well that trying to resize the window is futile.